# Add to passbook not working

Tags: ios6, passbook, passkit

I am having a lot of trouble with this and I have finally decided to come here. I feel as if I am making a noob mistake. I created a Passbook pass and I am using `PKAddPassesViewController` to add the pass. When I present the pass controller, the pass shows up correctly. However, when I decide to press "add" nothing happens, nothing gets logged or anything. After investigating, I added a delegate and the delegate method is as follows:

```
-(void)addPassesViewControllerDidFinish:(PKAddPassesViewController *)controller
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, instead for the normal animated dismiss, The controller dismisses as of the app crashes but instead goes to the previous view controller. This is absolutely driving me nuts and any help at all would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addPassesViewControllerDidFinish` is an optional delegate method, and it is called *after* the `PKAddPassesViewController` view controller has been dismissed.  In your case, your code could be crashing because you are attempting to dismiss the parent view controller (self).

When 'nothing happens' when adding a pass, it is usually because the pass is not valid.  The pass signature does not get checked until after the 'Add' button has been pressed, so this may explain why you see a pass displayed, but then it disappears after you press add.  If everything works as expected if you press cancel, then this is probably your issue.

To get more info on what is happening to the Pass, turn on 'Additional Logging' in the Developer Settings on your device, then check the console log of the device (from the Organizer) as you try to add the pass to see if it gives any clues as to why the add is failing.

Comment: I tried everything mentioned here, however the issue just isnt with my own app. I tried sample pass book code from raywendelich and it still didnt work! I then tried on multiple phones and it still didnt work, so there is obviously something going on here...

Comment: Does your pass load on a device if you add it via a URL or mail attachment? If sample code doesn't work, then the Pass seems like the culprit variable.  What happens when you hit the cancel button?

Comment: In that case, I'm almost 100% sure it is your .pkpass bundle that is causing the problem.

Comment: This worked, I eventually found what was causing the error and eventually fixed it by using apples signpass tool. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. If you are interested in a simpler way to dynamically create and sign passes, then you may want to [check us out](https://create.passkit.com)